# Using variables within a SQL*Plus connect string

Tags: scripting, connection-string, session-variables, sqlplus, ksh

I have a SQL*Plus routine embedded inside of a KornShell (ksh) script.

As long as I hard code my SID in the connect string, the entire routine works as intended.

However, depending on whether I am in debug mode, or production mode, will depend on which SID I want to connect to.

When I attempt to use a variable in place of the hardcoded SID, inside of the connect string, it continually errors out.

I have tried single quotes, double quotes, braces, back-slashing the `$`, etc.

But, nothing that I have tried, short of hardcoding the SID in this connect string seems to work.

Here is an example of my connect string:

sqlplus UserID/"Passwd"@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HostID)(PORT = Port))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = $ORASID)))

Remember that it works, if I simply hardcode the SID:

```
sqlplus UserID/"Passwd"@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = HostID)(PORT = Port))(CONNECT_DATA = (SID = OraSID)))
```

Can anyone tell me how I can get the SID to work as a fed-in variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
sqlplus -s $user/$password@$SID
```

and so does this:

```
sqlplus -s $myLogin
```

where $myLogin = user/password@SID

Comment: $user as ${user} .. Just a standard!!